# Do creatures come into play tapped if they come into play at the same time as a card which says "Creatures come into play tapped"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

An example situation :

[Living Death](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Living%20Death) resolves while there is a [Urabrask the Hidden](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Urabrask%20the%20Hidden) in my graveyard and another creature in my opponent's graveyard. Urabrask says "Creatures your opponents control enter the battlefield tapped."

Will my opponent's creature come into play tapped if it enters the battlefield at the same time as Urabrask?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, your opponent's creatures *will not* enter tapped.

The ability "Creatures your opponents control enter the battlefield tapped" creates a replacement effect on creatures entering the battlefield. [Rule 614.4](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Replacement_Effect) says

> Replacement effects must exist before the appropriate event occurs -- they can't "go back in time" and change something that's already happened.

Since your Urabrask wasn't on the battlefield *before* your opponent's creature entered, it's ability does not effect that creatures.

Comment: One exception: 614.12 allows for effects to come from the permanent itself if they affect only that permanent (as opposed to a general subset of permanents that includes it), allowing for [Akoum Refuge](http://magiccards.info/c13/en/272.html) first ability to work. That exception does not apply here.